# Access the serial port in a platform-independant way

Tags: c++, c, serial-port, platform-independent

I have a task to create a program, that control a device over RS-232 from a desktop station. Currently I am at the planning stage and need some general help selecting a language and overall approach to the problem.

The program should build and run under Linux (mostly Ubuntu) and Windows (XP, 7) on 32 and 64 bit Intel processors. The workstation might have physical COM ports or (more probably) USB-RS232 converter.

Currently my best bet is a C++ program, built with CMake conditionally. Is there some way, using some language, to configure and access serial ports (including emulated through a USB), that is platform-independent? If no, what would be a good approach to this problem?

*Suggestions up to now*:
 *  [C++ with Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html)
 * [python with pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html Serial Ports?

Comment: @ForEveR, I suspected something in that direction might be coming up. Boost seems to be the answer to all questions on Earth :)

Comment: Since you're looking for portability have you considered scripting languages?

Comment: Python with its pySerial might be a good choice - http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @therefromhere, I "speak" only bash, and that is far from portable. I would learn another language if someone tells me "this is just for the task", however currently I have no clues in any direction.

Comment: If you can get away with using python, use pyserial.  I've used it many times.  You'll have your program working in about 10 minutes and 5 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Boost Asio (using C++)!

(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

It's guaranteed to be platform independent: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html

Though what makes it much better than any other libraries is that it supports asynchronous communications. I think that feature makes it very useful in your device-control software. And don't forget that it is part of Boost whose libraries are very reliable.

I've used it on my sms messaging program (using AT commands sent through serial/COM ports).

Hope this solves your problem as it has solved mine.

Comment: :( For half an year I have been looking for an excuse to learn python and now you prevent yet another one. I blame you! I'll give Boost a go and if it handles the usb converter I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Sorry for the (huge!) delay. If you have time please look on this: http://www.webalice.it/fede.tft/serial_port/serial_port.html

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the way to go for me.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look on the Java [Communication Api](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html)

For C / C++, you can use **/dev/ttySx** device under linux, MacOS and Cygwin (for Windows).
If the USB-RS232 converter is based on a FTDI chip, you can have a look on the libFTDI.
Finally, you can eventually check [RS-232 for Linux and Windows](http://www.teuniz.net/RS-232/)

Comment: Using Cygwin implies a little prformance cost, but sometimes it can be negligible