# Com port library in C or C++

Tags: c++, c, serial-port

i need to manage a COM printer port by Tomcat webserver. I tried a lot of java solutions, for example RxTx library but i had a lot of troubles: when i switch off the printer the jvm crashed!!
Now i would like to use an jvm external library linked by JNA, so i need a **C or C++ library with raw methods to read and write to a COM port**. This library **should be compile under windows or linux**. Can I find somethings already done? (I can not write programs in C or C++).

Thank you.

Comment: I solved my Java-serialport troubles with Jssc library!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)!

Its guaranteed to be fully portable. Its also very reliable. I've actually used it in my own application (SMS sender through gsm devices using AT commands).

Please also see: [Access the serial port in a platform-independant way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088071/access-the-serial-port-in-a-platform-independant-way/12088633#12088633)

Answer (score 1):

Try another one library: http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/
This project targeted for Qt users.
Supports Qt4 and Qt5 both!

Answer (score 0):

In case you're looking for something lightweight with no additional dependencies, I'd like to plug my own library https://github.com/nullpunktTUD/SerialPort

It is fully cross-platform and supports enumeration.